# Annotation chart google function after rangechange

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I'm using the annotation chart and the map from google api, I would like to know if there's anyway to trigger a function after the range change when the user's clic releases. I just find this `google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'rangechange', feed_with_chartMap);` in the documentation but the function is not only called when the clic is realeased but everytime the range change. I want to feed my map whith an ajax call like that :

```
function feed_with_chartMap(e){
          waiting("Updating the map","loading_map");
          $("#loading_map").show();
          var start = e.start / 1000;
          var end = e.end / 1000;
          $.ajax({
            url: url_current_json,
            data:{
              origin:"timeline_json",
              query: query_value,
              NElat: map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
              NElng: map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng(),
              SWlat: map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(),
              SWlng: map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng(),
              dateInit: start,
              dateEnd: end,
              tag: tag_value
            },
            context: document.body,
            success: function(data){
              clear_map();
              print_map(data.map);
              $("#loading_map").hide();
              refresh_events("timeline");
            }
          });
        }
```

If i call this fonction with 'rangechange' event it's really too slow, that's why i would like to call this only when the user finished to change the end or start in the annotation chart.

I hope to be clear in my explanation.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're describing.  If you describe what you're trying to achieve instead, maybe someone can give you some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution to my question, i just post it here if someone else try to do the same. Maybe there's better solution but this one do what i want so that's ok.

Instead of using `google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'rangechange', feed_with_chartMap);`

I use `$('#chart_AnnotationChart_rangeControlContainer g[transform]').click(feed_with_chartMap);`

It calls my function when the clic is realeased on one of range selector in my chart map.